# Updating a database in window form and c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am adding records to my database via a windows form. But when ever I add a new record it doesnt update until I close the app and then start again. Even though I think I am telling it to update (Im obv not!!)

Do I need a new varibale to update the database? Im a little stuck.

EDIT: All code on this..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace MediaManagementSystem
{
public partial class AddMedia : Form
{
    //database var
    OleDbConnection m_cnADONetConnection = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataAdapter m_daDataAdapter;
    OleDbDataAdapter m_cbCommandBuilder;
    DataTable m_dtMedia = new DataTable();
    int m_rowPosition = 0;

    public AddMedia()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //load up file dialog and find media
        if (addFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //add media file name to file path text box
            txtFilePath.Text = addFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add the new record to the database
        DataRow drNewRow = m_dtMedia.NewRow();
        drNewRow["FilePath"] = txtFilePath.Text;
        drNewRow["Subject"] = txtSubject.Text;
        drNewRow["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;
        drNewRow["Keywords"] = txtKeywords.Text;
        drNewRow["MediaType"] = AddComboBox.Text;
        m_dtMedia.Rows.Add(drNewRow);

        m_daDataAdapter.Update(m_dtMedia);
        m_rowPosition = m_dtMedia.Rows.Count - 1;
        this.ShowCurrentRecord();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void AddMedia_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //link to the database and conect to database
        m_cnADONetConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MediaManagementSystem\MediaManagementSystem\bin\Debug\MediaDB.mdb";
        m_cnADONetConnection.Open();
        OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(m_cnADONetConnection.ConnectionString);

        m_daDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Media", m_cnADONetConnection);

        OleDbCommandBuilder m_cbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(m_daDataAdapter);
        m_daDataAdapter.Fill(m_dtMedia);
        m_daDataAdapter.Update(m_dtMedia);
    }

    public void ShowCurrentRecord()
    {
        m_daDataAdapter.Update(m_dtMedia);   

        if (m_dtMedia.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            txtFilePath.Text = "";
            txtSubject.Text = "";
            txtTitle.Text = "";
            txtKeywords.Text = "";
            AddComboBox.Text = "";
            return;
        }
        txtFilePath.Text = m_dtMedia.Rows[m_rowPosition]["FilePath"].ToString();
        txtSubject.Text = m_dtMedia.Rows[m_rowPosition]["Subject"].ToString();
        txtTitle.Text = m_dtMedia.Rows[m_rowPosition]["Title"].ToString();
        txtKeywords.Text = m_dtMedia.Rows[m_rowPosition]["Keywords"].ToString();
        AddComboBox.Text = m_dtMedia.Rows[m_rowPosition]["MediaType"].ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "it doesnt update until I close the app and then start again" So you close it and reopen it and you see your changes?

Comment: Sidenote: you're calling `m_daDataAdapter.Update(m_dtMedia);` twice when you AddButton_Click

Comment: Thats what makes me think it is working but Im just updating incorrectly.

Comment: Banging you were correct that answer you deleted was not correct just tried it.

Comment: See edit for all code on this form

Comment: Is this your "ADD" form and you have another interface to show all your records?

Comment: yes correct do you want to see this?

Comment: Not yet.. and what you're saying is that the OTHER MAIN form is not showing what you just added?

Comment: Correct, although when I close it down and re open the app its there. So I know its updating just not in real time so to speak. Want to take this to chat?mods will shut it down if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would best if you use DataSet and then update the records in it. Finally you need to call AcceptChanges() after the update() command to commit the changes with dataset something as below also reload the data after to enter to get the recent data info: 
dataset.AcceptChanges()

Answer (score 0):

After you open AddMedia form from your MAIN form, you need to RALOAD all your records again. Look how the form is doing it when it opens and do the same AFTER you open your AddMedia form ;)

Comment: Sorry this is as far as I'll take it since I have other things to do. You should be able to figure it out from here if you're genuinely trying!

Comment: `code private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddMedia AddMedia = new AddMedia();
            AddMedia.Show();
            m_daDataAdapter.Update(m_dtMedia);
        }` Still nothing. Shouldnt it be when I close the add form I then reload?

Comment: On your MAIN, what are you using to show all your records? DataGridView? Whatever it is, it wasn't updated!!

Comment: That is the code for the button which open the AddMedia from the Mainform